# Crossdomain jQuery ajax request was not called and give error status "parsererror"

Tags: jquery-ajaxq

I am trying to call cross domain url. which has response text as below.and it is valid json response.

```
[{"LANG_CODE":"UK_EN","COU_ISO_CODE":"BGR"},
{"LANG_CODE":"UK_EN","COU_ISO_CODE":"HUN"},
{"LANG_CODE":"UK_EN","COU_ISO_CODE":"PRT"},
{"LANG_CODE":"UK_EN","COU_ISO_CODE":"UGA"}]
```

Jquery ajax code which i am using for calling cross.

```
$.ajax({
     url: "http://someDomainName/restfulservice/Api/Countries/Get_Json",
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     crossDomain: true,
     async: false,
     success: function (data) {
       alert("success >> "+data);
     },
     error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert("error : "+errorThrown + ", textStatus >> "+textStatus);
     }       
});
```

every time it goes to error block. when i inspect this service in browser then it gives response text with valid json string.but through code i am getting error `"jQuery18305917718204907095_1409810925309 was not called, status: parsererror".`

while this code is working for the url **"http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON?lat=47.3&lng=9&username=demo"**.

what could be the issue for same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sending back JSON but you have said `dataType: 'jsonp'`. JSON is not JSONP.

Either change the service to support JSONP or change the client to expect JSON (which might require you to find some other way to circumvent the same origin policy)

Comment: @Quentin-this service is used globally so i can't change in service. how to make same for client side ?